# How to convert from char to Platform::String^ (C++/CLI)

Tags: string, windows-8, c++-cli

How do you convert from a char to a `Platform::String^`?

The documentation for `Platform::String` is here but does not mention how to convert to and from different data types.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh755812(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh755812%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ref new Platform::String(&ch, 1);
```

Answer (score 12):

I found a method to convert `char[]` to `Platform::String`.

```
char char_str[] = "Char string";
std::string s_str = std::string(char_str);
std::wstring wid_str = std::wstring(s_str.begin(), s_str.end());
const wchar_t* w_char = wid_str.c_str();
Platform::String^ p_string = ref new Platform::String(w_char);
```

I hope there is a more efficient way than my method.

Comment: I've looked for shorter methods.  This seems to be it.

Answer (score 2):

```
String^ StringFromAscIIChars(char* chars)
{   
    size_t newsize = strlen(chars) + 1;
    wchar_t * wcstring = new wchar_t[newsize];
    size_t convertedChars = 0;
    mbstowcs_s(&convertedChars, wcstring, newsize, chars, _TRUNCATE);
    String^ str=ref new Platform::String(wcstring);
    delete[] wcstring;
    return str;
}
```

Also see this MSDN link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235631.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Use the appropriate constructor for the job:

```
// this is a pointer to the start of an array of char16
char16* c;

// this is the number of chars in the array
// (not including the null char if the array is null-terminated)
int n;

Platform::String^ str(c, n);
```

If your "array of char16s" is null-terminated, you can also use this:

```
Platform::String^ str(c);
```

Comment: Copying exactly what you have into my code gives this error C3149: 'Platform::String' : cannot use this type here without a top-level '^'

Comment: @joe Apparently you have to change String to String^, but do not ask me why. I'll never touch the CLI dialect, even with a 10 meter pole.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that:

```
#include <cvt/wstring>
#include <codecvt>
...
stdext::cvt::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>> convert;
std::wstring wide_string = convert.from_bytes(char_ptr);
Platform::String^ platform_string = ref new Platform::String(wide_string.c_str());
```